# What the situation will make channel.getExitStatus() return 1

Tags: jsch

```java
private String test(String command){
    channel = sesConnection.openChannel("exec");
    ((ChannelExec) channel).setCommand(command);
    BufferedReader br = 
    new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(channel.getInputStream()));
    InputStream error = ((ChannelExec) channel).getErrStream();
    channel.connect();
    StringBuffer outputstream = new StringBuffer();
    String msg = null;
    while ((msg = br.readLine()) != null) {
           outputstream.append(msg);            
    }
    System.out.println("Channel exit status:" + channel.getExitStatus());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- When the `command` finishes (so the "exec" channel closes) and returns exit code 1.
- Or when the channel even fails to open (what is typically when the `command` is not a valid command).

Comment: But if this command execute successful it will return 0 as a successful flag.

Comment: I've add a sentence as "System.out.println(channel.isClosed())" try to check whether the channel is closed and find that after that while loop, the channel has not closed yet.

Comment: So the command most probably did not completed successfully. Read the error output to see if there are any errors.

Comment: Do you know when JSCH will close the channel?

Comment: I'm not sure the sequence for channel.disconnect() and channel.isClosed().  Someone tell me we check the channel.getExitStatus() before channel.disconnect(). But when I should check the channel.isClosed() ?

Comment: Not sure. Generaly the channel is closed when the server or you ask for it to be closed. The server closes the "exec" channel when the command finishes. But I'm sure how this is all hooked to the `isClosed`. Anyway, this is not what this question is about.